# Using If and Vlookup, only outputting a date if it occurs before today

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a project where I am using IF and VLOOKUP formulas to search if a cell includes a date, and only a single date. If it has a single date, output "Actual", if it does not include a date or includes a range of dates, it should output "Projected". This works well with this formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheets!A:B, 2, FALSE)*1, "")=0, "",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE)*1, ""))), "Actual", "Projected")
```

The sheet 2 values include 1 past date and 1 future date. When Using this formula I get what I mentioned above, but now I only want it to output "Actual" if the date is a past date. And a future date should say "Projected". I have tried the formula below, but it only outputs "Projected" for all dates.

```
=IF((ISNUMBER(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheets!A:B, 2, FALSE)*1, "")=0, "",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!A:B, 2, FALSE)*1, ""))))<TODAY(), "Actual", "Projected")
```

Any suggestions or help?

Mock Up Data

Sheet 1

[image]

Sheet 2

[image]

Comment: please mock up some data and expected output.  It will help us understand what you are trying to do.  Include all scenarios that you describe.

Comment: @ScottCraner I have added in the mock up data

Comment: Those picture do not help as we do not see to what the formula references. Your formula referes to A3 and A:B on the other page.  There is no references.

Comment: @ScottCraner updated

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheets!A:B, 2, FALSE)<=TODAY(),"Actual","Projected"),"ID Not Found")
```